# Return extra variable in data.table subset

Tags: r, data.table

Given a sample data.table

```
DT<-data.table(c(1:20), LETTERS[1:10], c("w","x","y","z"), rnorm(c(1:20)))
```

I would like to subset it according to, say, this:

```
DT[, .(V4=max(V4)), by=.(V3)]
```

returning

```
   V3        V1
1:  w 1.1939909
2:  x 1.6321958
3:  y 0.5836792
4:  z 0.4115887
```

My question is: how can I get it to return an additional variable (column), but without sorting by that column? So, how can I include the appropriate V2 column in the above subset to get:

```
   V3        V4  V2
1:  w 1.1939909  A
2:  x 1.6321958  F
3:  y 0.5836792  G
4:  z 0.4115887  J
```

Doing this: `DT[, .(V4=max(V4), V2), by=.(V3)]`
or this: `DT[, .(V4=max(V4)), by=.(V3, V2)]`
just returns the entire dataset.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `DT[DT[,.I[which.max(V4)], by=V3]$V1]` or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `.SD` to subset the rows based on the index of maximum value of "V4", grouped by "V3"

```
DT[, .SD[which.max(V4)], by = V3]
```

or `order` the "V4" grouped by "V3" and select the first row

```
DT[order(-V4), head(.SD, 1) , by = V3]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude the original `V1`, you can do:

```
DT[ , .(V4[idx <- which.max(V4)], V2[idx]), by = V3]
```

Or

```
DT[ , .SD[which.max(V4)], by = V3, .SDcols = c("V2", "V4")]
```

Both approaches have their appeal for different situations when we'd like to do more than this simple operation.